# how to update layout xml for custom theme in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I am creating a custom theme for Magento 2. I need to customize the layout existng in app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[CustomTheme]/Magento_Theme/layout] whose name is default.xml.

I have changed it by adding and changing some things, however, changes are not taken into account. I always see the original layout.

I have disabled cache, however, just in case, I have flushed it but it was unsuccessful.

How can I reload the layout? maybe it was stored in database, but, how can I refresh it?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: have you set your theme from admin panel? Theme set from store -> configuration > general design

Comment: of course I have. I told that the new theme was used at first, and in fact, if I see the database entry in theme table, I see my theme, and I am certain it is being used. The problem is when I update the xml file for the theme, It does not refresh the changes.

Comment: clear cache and remove var folder and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened was that I was referencing the invalid block name. Thanks anyway.

Comment: or if it fixed the question accept your own answer so is doesn't up in the list of open questions